# Django TestCase client.logout() is not logging out user correctly

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm writing some tests for Django. I'm having trouble with the client.logout() method, which doesn't seem to be logging the test client out.

Here's my setUp():

```
def setUp(self): 
        # Set up a user to use with all of the tests and log in the user.
        User.objects.create_user(username='temporary', password='temporary')
        self.client.login(username='temporary', password='temporary')

        # Create second user for later use.
        User.objects.create_user(username='temporary2', password='temporary2')
```

And here's my test method:

```
def test_user_can_only_access_own_recipes(self):
        """
        A user should only be able to access recipes they have created.
        """
        # temporary1 user already logged in via setUp().
        user_1_recipe = self.create_recipe()
        self.client.logout()

        # Login second user and create recipe. 
        self.client.login(username='temporary2', password='temporary2')
        user_2_recipe = self.create_recipe()

        # Response_owned is a recipe made by user 2, who is still logged in, so the recipe should 
        be viewable. 
        # Response_not_owned is recipe made by user 1 and should not be viewable as they are 
        logged out.

        response_owned = self.client.get(
             reverse('recipes:display_recipe', args=(user_2_recipe.id,)))
        response_not_owned = self.client.get(
            reverse('recipes:display_recipe', args=(user_1_recipe.id,)))
        
        self.assertEqual(response_not_owned.status_code, 403)
        # Convert to str, otherwise Django compares 'temporary' with just temporary no quotes.
        self.assertEqual(str(user_1_recipe.user), 'temporary')
        self.assertEqual(user_2_recipe.user, 'temporary2')
        self.assertEqual(response_owned.status_code, 200)
```

This fails with the assertion error:

```
self.assertEqual(user_2_recipe.user, 'temporary2')
AssertionError: <User: temporary> != 'temporary2'
```

So my test should create a recipe owned by user 1. User 1 should be logged out, and user 2 is then logged in, and a recipe is created owned by user 2. The test should check whether the second user can access their own recipe, and can't access the first user's recipe. Trouble is, only the first user seems to be logged in, as the assertion error states that the second recipe is still owned by the first user. I don't think logout() is logging out the first user at all. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Please see the create_recipe() method below. After comments from Iain Shelvington it's become apparent that I had been adding the same user 'temporary' to every recipe created by the create_recipe method, by including this line:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='temporary'),
```

The amended method taking a username as an argument looks as follows, and the test can now be modified to allow the post to be from any user you like.

```
def create_recipe(self, recipe_name='Test Recipe', username='temporary'):
        """
        Creates a recipe with default values and a modifiable name to be 
        used in tests.
        """
        recipe = RecipeCard.objects.create(
            user = User.objects.get(username=username),
            # REMAINDER OF CODE
```

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
def create_recipe(self, recipe_name='Test Recipe'):
        """
        Creates a recipe with default values and a modifiable name to be 
        used in tests.
        """
        # Object is receiving default values that can be changed when method 
        # is used 
        recipe = RecipeCard.objects.create(
            user = User.objects.get(username='temporary'),
            recipe_name=recipe_name, 
            source = 'Test Source', 
            servings = 3,
            active_time_hours = 2,
            active_time_minutes = 15,
            total_time_hours = 2, 
            total_time_minutes = 15, 
            recipe_description = 'Test Description')
        recipe.save()

        ingredient = Ingredient.objects.create(
            ingredient_name = 'Test Ingredient',
            quantity = 1, 
            recipe = recipe)
        ingredient.save()

        method = MethodStep.objects.create(
            step = 'Test Step',
            recipe = recipe)
        method.save()

        # Make sure you return the created recipe object for use when method
        # is called in tests.
        return recipe
```

Comment: You need to convert the user to a string like you did in the assertion before, better yet use the username `self.assertEqual(user_2_recipe.user.username, 'temporary2')`. You successfully get a 403 when trying to access the first recipe though, can you share the `create_recipe` method?

Comment: You didn't actually add the method

Comment: Hi Iain - somehow with a single comment you've mostly troubleshooted my problem. I'm adding  the create_recipe() method to the OP now. When setting the user for the recipe I'm using 

`user = User.objects.get(username='temporary')` 

which is adding the same user each time. Is there any way to request the current logged in user instead?

Comment: I'm not aware of a simple way to get the currently logged in user, perhaps the `create_recipe` method should take a username as an argument or a user object and call it from the setUp method

Comment: It works! Not sure how I missed that after many hours of troubleshooting, but very happy that you managed to solve it - many thanks for your time and help!